# Comparing boost functions - function signature?

Tags: c++, function, boost

To start of, I have read the other topics on the subject here on SO and I've read the [boost faq aswell](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/function/faq.html#id1284470) and I still do not feel I have an answer to my problem below.

I want to have a sort-of delegate system using function wrappers like boost::function. I solve this by storing boost::function objects in a vector. The problem comes with a method like UnregisterCallback(), where one expects to compare the supplied callback with the ones stored and remove it if found. From what I've gathered around the webs, it is because boost function objects are not compareable.

Yet, using a template as per #2, I can make it work as I want it too. See example below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "boost/function.hpp"

typedef boost::function<void (int)> Callback;

class CallbackHandler
{
public:
    void AddCallback(const Callback& callback)
    {
        mCallbacks.push_back(callback);
    }

    // #1: dosnt work
    void RemoveCallback(const Callback& callback)
    {
        mCallbacks.erase(std::find(mCallbacks.begin(), mCallbacks.end(), callback));
    }

    // #2: works
    template <typename T>
    void RemoveCallback(const T& callback)
    {
        mCallbacks.erase(std::find(mCallbacks.begin(), mCallbacks.end(), callback));
    }

private:
    std::vector<Callback> mCallbacks;

};


void testCB(int i)
{
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CallbackHandler handler;
    handler.AddCallback(testCB);
    handler.RemoveCallback(testCB);

    return 0;
}
```

But I cannot/do not want to use a templated function, so I was wondering, since it obviously works there must be a valid function signature to make it work right? Yet I cannot for the life of me figure out what it is, or why the template version works while the other dosnt.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can't / don't want to use [`boost::signals2`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/signals2.html)?

Comment: Not if I can avoid it - surely there must be a solution using boost::function?

Comment: If the template version works, why not keep it and throw out the last one?

Comment: @NicolasLouisGuillemot in C++ it's usually important to know why something works, not just that it works in one specific case, because it could be causing undefined behaviour that just happens to work in that case.

Comment: I think the problem is that this comparison had to behave differently for different "target function" types stored inside the (type-erasing) `boost::function`. The `boost::function` object can contain a function pointer, some `boost::bind` expression, a true function object etc. Therefore, you had to first check the types of the stored-functions-to-be-compared are equal (e.g. via `boost::function::target_type`) and then based on that type do the actual comparison. I suspect the template version does exactly that (based on the template parameter `T`, via `boost::function::target<T>`).

Comment: @DavidBrown for sure. I think we'd have to see a test case to understand why the templated one works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::function` objects can be compared to other functors and function pointers, but not to other `boost::function` objects (see reference [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/functionN.html#idp17998976-bb)). When you call the templated version, `T` becomes a `void(*)(int)` function pointer, so `operator==` is valid, can see that the types are the same, and simply compares the underlying function pointer in the `boost::function` object with the function pointer you passed in. For the non-templated version you are comparing two `boost::function` objects, which is not valid.

Comment: Yepp, that works fine. Now that I think about, is there any point in using boost::function at all then if I can just pass around pure function pointers? Why would I want to use boost function?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan because you might want to use some other object that overloads `operator()` such the result of `boost::bind`, a lambda, or some custom functor. `boost::function` allows you to store any object that can be called with that signature, while storing function pointers restricts you to only using function pointers.